# update google chart dynamically on dropdown using ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, drop-down-menu, google-visualization

I have to display google chart according to dropdown value, which contains shop ids
i am retrieving the data from mysql, no problem with values, i am retrieving the data according to shop id from ajax, and just confirming it in the input box it is also fine.

but i dont know how to update that chart with those values, without reloading the page.
here is my google chart code with hardcoded values.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>newChart</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart()
          {var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Company & Model', 'Views'],['Samsung Hero Music E1232B',5],['Samsung Galaxy Y S5360',7],['Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830',7],['Karbonn K 1212',2],]);      
            var options = {
              title: 'Most Popular Item ',
              hAxis: {title: 'Brand', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('MPI_chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>COLUMN CHART FOR MOST POPULAR ITEM </h3>
        Select Shop  <select id="MPI_selected_shop" onchange="MPI_set_shop(this.value);">           
                <option value="all_Shops">All Shops</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                 </select>
<input type="text" id="sd"  />

        <div id="MPI_chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

here is my ajax code in the same page within script tag

```
var xmlHttp

                function MPI_set_shop(str)
                { 
                    alert(str);
                    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
                    if (xmlHttp==null)
                    {
                      alert ("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                      return;
                    } 
                    var url="chart.php";
                    url=url+"?q="+str;
                    alert(url);

                    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
                    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
                    xmlHttp.send(null);
                }

                function stateChanged() 
                { 
                    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                    { 
                        document.getElementById("sd").value=xmlHttp.responseText;

                        $st=xmlHttp.responseText;

                        alert($st);

                    }
                }
```

here is my chart.php from where i am getting the formatted data from mysql using ajax

```
<?php
 $testid=0;
$testid=$_REQUEST["q"];
//echo $testid;

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                if (!$con)
                {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }
                // Select Database
                mysql_select_db("mysql", $con) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());;

                                    $qMostPopularItem = "SELECT t.pr_id,p.pdt_company_name,p.pdt_model_name,SUM(t.count) AS count FROM tmp AS t INNER JOIN product_mapping AS p ON t.pr_id = p.pr_id AND t.shop_id =$testid GROUP BY pr_id ORDER BY t.count DESC;";

                                        $mpi = mysql_query($qMostPopularItem,$con) or die('Could not fetch MPI: ' . mysql_error());

                                      while($infoMPISW = mysql_fetch_assoc($mpi)) 
                                        { 
                                                echo "['".$infoMPISW['pdt_company_name']." ";
                                                echo $infoMPISW['pdt_model_name'] ."',";
                                                echo $infoMPISW['count'],"],";

                                        }

                      ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ajax Response Call drawChart() function again with new values. Below is the code which I have tried.

Index file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
          google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart()
          {
            alert('called');
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Company & Model', 'Views'],['Samsung Hero Music E1232B',5],['Samsung Galaxy Y S5360',7],['Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830',7],['Karbonn K 1212',2],]);      
            var options = {
              title: 'Most Popular Item ',
              hAxis: {title: 'Brand', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('MPI_chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
          function drawChart2()
          {
            alert('called2');
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Company & Model', 'Views'],['Samsung Music E1232B',5],['Samsung S5360',7],['Samsung S5830',7],['Karbonn K 1212',2],]);      
            var options = {
              title: 'Most Popular Item ',
              hAxis: {title: 'Brand', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('MPI_chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
          </script>
<script>
var xmlHttp

                function MPI_set_shop(str)
                { 
                    alert(str);
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        //google.load("visualization", str, {packages:["corechart"]});
        //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        drawChart2(); // Note down here..
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","chart.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
                }                
</script>

<h3>COLUMN CHART FOR MOST POPULAR ITEM </h3>
        Select Shop  <select id="MPI_selected_shop" onchange="MPI_set_shop(this.value);">           
                <option value="all_Shops">All Shops</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                 </select>
<input type="text" id="sd"  />

        <div id="MPI_chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Note that I have created another function named drawChart2() but if you call drawChart() then also it will give you alert with "called". You just need to pass the new values in it. Hope above answer will help you. Most importantly I have done nothing except callback function. [Though I changed javascript ajax code but that wont be any issue.]

Comment: data in the above code is hardcoded it is working fine, but I am fetching the data from database and storing it in a variable and the  format in that variable itself, as i wanted, means adding those square brackets and all that. but instead of "displaying the values of that variable it is displaying the variable name. how should i resolve it.

Comment: First of all great that my anwser helped you but as of now you are passing a string to ajax response. You need to pass array itself. You can use json to get data back and pass as array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into google chart's dashboards in which you can bind a chart (e.g. bar chart) with a control (string filter - text box, category picker - drop down, number range selector - slider)? This is because I see no instances of ChartWrapper and Data Table View option.

Without using dashboards, a simple way is to just ajax request new data and call chart_ name.draw( new_chart_data, options ); which will redraw the entire chart. Also, you may face resolution/display problems depending on the size of your dataset.

Comment: Google chart's controls and filters are great but limited to column values and options. Ajex is the only option I guess.