# dynamically update google chart using dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-visualization

Im trying to plot a set of data from the database using google chart (visualisation api) using Bortosky Library

http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/

to convert ASP.NET data table to Google Data table.
I want the user to select which data table it should retrive from data base using a drop down menu. I had read a solution

[update google chart dynamically on dropdown using ajax and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100390/updating-google-chart-dynamically-on-dropdown-using-ajax-and-php)

But I dont know AJAX or PHP to do this. Is there any simpler method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a video on youtube and answered your specific question on this site to another user.
Let me know if this is what you're looking for.
[putting array from vb codebehind into javascript datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333664/putting-array-from-vb-codebehind-into-javascript-datatable/13333744#13333744)

Comment: not exactly.. This is the  link to my draft website http://128.39.35.252/Weather/   in that you can see there is a drop down list menu I want to change the plot below it according to this selection by user.. and Im working on C# not VB..